# Problems while importing mysql dump (The table ... may not be created in the reserved tablespace ...)

Tags: mysql

Backup was taking too long, and my windows was growing short, so I decided to create a slave in a container just to run backups and maybe a few queries that are too slow for my taste.

I did a complete dump with:

```
mysqldump --skip-lock-tables \
          --single-transaction \
          --flush-logs \
          --source-data=2 \
          --all-databases \
          --routines  > "BKP.sql"
```

Create my generic container using docker hub mysql image, but when I try to import my dump, I run in the following error message:

```
ERROR 3723 (HY000) at line 524: The table 'replication_asynchronous_connection_failover' may not be created in the reserved tablespace 'mysql'.
```

I never encounter this error. I tried search it and found a few questions, but apparently my best option was "just edit the dump", which is not a viable option because the thing has over 600k lines and weight 20GB. I tough it was one of those rare occasions that happen twice in our lives, and run the same backup, with the exactly same error.

Any ideas? If you know why this happen, please explain so I will not have a stroke when I desperately need to import my backup and end up with this error.

Comment: You probably want to avoid dumping (and restoring) the mysql database.

Comment: I always saw dumping as the preferable way to backup mysql databases (not a DBA in any way tho). You would suggest that I use binary backups? I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I mean don't use `--all-databases`, only dump your specific ones. The `mysql` database normally contains system objects that you don't want to restore to another MySQL instance

Comment: Hum my bad. I was using the --all-databases because it would make my life so much easy while setting up replication (same users with same passwords and grants).

Comment: "because it would make my life so much easy" -- How'd it work so far?

Comment: Good point. At less is not friday...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I manage to solve the problem by editing the file (remove the troublesome tables and their data), and decided to document how I manage to edit a 20GB file because it may help others.

First I was forced to split the giant file in smaller files. I manage to achieve that by using the command `split -b 1GB BKP.sql`, this way, I break the file in smaller 1GB files that can "easily" edited by VIM or your desired editor.

Then I edit the file. Since I knew it was just on line 524, I assume that it was in the first chunk, and opened VIM without any plug-in with `vim -u NONE xa`.

Then, after save, I joined all files together using `cat xa* > dump.sql`, and it was done.  (Notice that in my case xa* was enough because it did not go longer than "xau", but it may be different if you have a bigger file or chose smaller chunks).

Answer (score 0):

> Solution is either one of the following:
>
> Exclude the system database 'mysql' in the logical dump and perform
> the backup of user-defined databases with --databases option.
>
> Restore the backup on same 8.0.26 or higher versions.

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2809554_1.html